# BLE broadcast without pairing

Tags: ionic-framework, bluetooth, cordova-plugins, bluetooth-lowenergy, eddystone

I'm working on a physical web oriented application.

I would like to have some devices that continuously broadcast string messages using bluetooth low energy.
The end point is a ionic application that should just receive and show this messages when required.

Is it possible to implement this kind of behaviour **without a paring** phase between the bluetooth broadcaster and the mobile phone?

At the moment I worked with with eddystone protocol, building a beacon with my raspberry pi, but I have some limitations due to 17 characters length constraint of url sizes. (I'm using url as a string to pass data).

Comment: Beacons use BLE advertising frames for broadcasting, and these frames are limited in size. Thus the ~20 bytes available.

Comment: Ok thanks. Is it possible to implement a broadcaster with no pairing using BLE - cordova application?

Answer (score 1):

You do not need to pair mobile devices with beacon devices to receive their signals.  Beacon signals are sent as Bluetooth LE advertisements which may be read by all nearby BLE devices without pairing.  This is true for both iOS and Android.

If you plan to use Ionic, there is a Cordova [iBeacon plugin](https://github.com/petermetz/cordova-plugin-ibeacon) you can use.  I am not aware of one for Eddystone.

With iBeacon you are even more limited on data passing, pretty much limited to four bytes on iOS.  In order to display different messages, you would have to embed a lookup table in your app or use a web service to do the same, either way looking up the string based on the beacon identifier.  With four bytes. That would give you 2**32 (4 billion) possible messages.

Full disclosure: I am the lead developer on the Android Beacon Library open source project, on which the aforementioned Cordova plugin is based.

Comment: Thank you. Actually the problem isn't related to # of messages and interfacing my app to eddystone. I'd like to know if there is any alternative approach (instead of using eddystone beacon) to broadcast a string with BLE and receive it into my app without the need of pairing devices. I'm getting troubles with url length constraints since I need to broadcast strings of 50-60 character. My intent is not to send url, but messages. At the moment I'm using eddystone-url improperly. Lookup table is not good to my purpose since messages have to be updated frequently and my app has to remain offline.

Comment: If you want to send the full message inside the a BLE packet without pairing, then you will be constrained by the max BLE advertisement packet length, which is basically 24 bytes of usable space for manufacturer advertisements.  You will need to reserve one or two bytes to identify it as likely your beacon type.  So you might get 22 ASCII characters in a custom beacon format.  You could potentially rotate the advertisement so a single byte tells you the number of adverts to combine together and which one this is (e.g. 4 of 15).  This would allow you to join together 16 adverts to get 300 chars

Comment: Yes thank you this was a solution that came to my mind. I don't think that commercial Beacon allow such a rotation, but I can implement it with my raspberry. So you think I can't implement a basic broadcast communication (Beacon like)  using only BLE ?

Comment: No, you cannot do this with a commercial beacon.  You would need a custom one like a Raspberry Pi or an Android or other Linux transmitter. But yes, you can do what you want with unpaired, unconnected BLE.